# Android App releases hasn't been rolled out

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I have just created my first app and want to upload on Google Play store.
I have proper account and [followed steps mentioned](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011) to publish my app.

I have submitted APK also.
In App release it is saying:

[image]

I am also aware of that warning shown on (https://play.google.com/apps/publish) that:

> Due to adjusted work schedules at this time, we are currently experiencing longer than usual review times
> Please expect review times of 7 days or longer.

So should I wait for 7 days?

But in main dashboard the app status below app name is "Draft".

What is the exact status of my submitted application?

Comment: Anybody please answer/help to understand this case

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same issue, its been 11 days for me, still the review is not yet done .., dont know whether i am on the right track !

Answer (score -1):

After clicking on Edit release. click on start full rollout button please then it will take 2-3 days to coming in production.